# How many application id's do I need for the like/Send button and SDK? Do I need one for each?

Tags: sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

When installing the [XFBML](http://www.tutorialarena.com/blog/what-is-xfbml.php) like/send button and the accompanying SDK, do I need to create separate application id's for both the button and the SDK?

Or can they both share the same application id?

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use the same appid for everything related to your Facebook app. When the browser loads this code it loads the SDK as well as the social plugins (such as like and send):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
</script>
```

This need only appear once per page where you are using social plugins, and you only need a single appid.